# Reorder R list by unconventionally ordered vector?

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have a list in R:

```
MyList <- list(A = rnorm(5), B = seq(10), C = letters)
```

Now let's say I also have a vector that matches the names of `MyList` but has them in a different sequence:

```
pattern <- c("B", "A", "C")
```

How can I sort `MyList` to match the order in `pattern`? The result should look like this, but with the original names still assigned.

```
NewList <- list(MyList[["B"]], MyList[["A"]], MyList[["C"]])
```

This seems straightforward if `pattern` has a natural order (e.g., ascending or descending). But what if it doesn't, so I can't use `sort` or `order`?

My ideal solution would only use base R.

Comment: Are you looking for this `sapply(pattern, function(x) MyList[[x]])`.

Comment: Just use name subsetting: `MyList[pattern]` or `MyList.reordered <-  MyList[pattern]` for assignment.

Comment: @imo Thats way better.

Comment: @lmo, got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to take a look at `?"["`. Specifically, the difference between `[[` and `[` confused me for a while. Here, the key thing to note is that you can use `[` to subset to multiple elements, while `[[` can only be used for one element.

So as @lmo points out, what you want to do here is `MyList[pattern]`. In case you didn't realize, this can work because `names(MyList)` matches up with the elements in `pattern` -- you can index/ subset not only by numerical index (e.g., `1:3`), but also by name (e.g., `c("A","B","C")`).

TLDR:

```
NewList <- MyList[pattern]
```